# 'git svn' does not start git-svn any more

Tags: linux, git, svn, git-svn

On my linux system (Centos 5.9) 'git svn' stopped working and I don't know why and how.

output is:

```
$ git svn
git: 'svn' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

`/usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn` exists and is fully working ( I can start it manually). And all other git sub commands seem to work (at least the ones I tried).

I'm not aware of any action which can have impact on git-svn like this (e.g. no updates/restarts)

How does git 'find' the git-svn script? Is there a mapping which might be broken or does git look into `/usr/libexec/git-core`?

What has happened?

Comment: Likely the CentOS folks saw fit for some reason to split `git-svn` into a separate package that you need to install, and isn't selected by default...

Comment: Have you possibly somehow acquired a second `git` executable on your path?

Comment: `which git` expands to '/usr/bin/git' so I doubt there is another git executable. But I'll give it a try and check which executables are being launched when run something like `git blame`.

Comment: `git-svn` has been installed and - thats the strange part - has been working until some days ago.

Answer (score -1):

try installing a libary something like 'libsvn-perl'.

Comment: I agree. I would suggest to delete this answer.

Comment: As I said - the command `/usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn` works as exspected. The svn perl bindings are installed and working.